# Getting 503 when trying to run Classic ASP on Win7 and IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, localhost

I am being asked to resurrect a classic ASP application for temporary use.  Wonderful.  Well, the pay's the same, so I am now trying to get the thing to run on my localhost so I can test it and so on.  I have copied all the files to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClassicASPapp.  Using IIS 7.5 I set this folder as an Application I get handed a 503.  Same result if I make it a Virtual Directory.

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Note that there is a file in wwwroot called "iisstart.htm".  If I double-click on the file from Windows Explorer, the browser displays the rendered HTML correctly.  If I try to navigate to the file using:

```
http://localhost/iisstart.htm
```

I get the 503 then, too.

What is going on? Is there some global setting I need to change?  Note that this is a new Windows 7 workstation.

I've checked and Classic ASP is definitely installed. The web site is associated with an application pool that has Classic ASP enabled, and 32-bit applications are also enabled.

**Event Log:**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WAS
Date:          8/8/2014 2:42:49 PM
Event ID:      5002
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESD71906.EClient.wa.lcl
Description:
Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WAS" Guid="{524B5D04-133C-4A62-8362-64E8EDB9CE40}" EventSourceName="WAS" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">5002</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-08-08T21:42:49.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>40664</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESD71906.EClient.wa.lcl</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="AppPoolID">DefaultAppPool</Data>
    <Binary>
    </Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

It is true that the application pool gets stopped.

**Test Connection / Authorization Detail:**

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make
>   sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the
>   physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has Read access to the physical path.
>   Then test these settings again.

Comment: Did you see anything interesting in the Event Log? Whenever you see a 5XX error, there is usually some info logged.

Comment: Well, @Nitz, I don't know if it's interesting, but I've added an entry I found in the Log.

Comment: This event is a good clue. Look for events happening a tiny bit earlier indicating the "series of failures". My money is on the login - is it using an application pool with a specific user (not the default identity)?

Comment: There is a series, but all of them say "The Windows Process Activation Service failed to create a worker process for the application pool 'DefaultAppPool'. The data field contains the error number."  I don't see a "data field".

Comment: Try looking for events in logs "Application" and "Security"

Comment: I don't have sufficient admin privileges to open the Security log on this workstation.  This is frustrating, @Nitz

Comment: I can tell you what I think it is - if you're using a custom identity for your application pool, it may be missing the privilege "logon as a service". Either [add it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), which requires admin privilege, or revert to the built in identity and see if the pages load

Comment: I can't find a privilege called "logon as a service" anywhere.  However, I do find that when I try to Test Connection, I get a successful Pass-through authentication, but Authorization gets the message details I added to the question above.  Does this make any sense, @Nitz ?

Comment: The above message is useless (I always see it, never relevant). The "logon as a service" privilege is part of a [User Right Assignments](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780182%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), not a simple topic. 
Might I suggest you create a VM to tinker with, assuming you don't have admin access to your machine? I think it'll be worth it.